# Scheduling tasks using java Timer taking into consideration DST

Tags: timer, scheduling, dst, timertask

I have a task that need to run at 10 irregular intervals of time throughout the day.
For e.g at 6am,8am,11am,4pm,4:30pm ...
I am planning to do it the following way:
Schedule the the first timer for 6am and when it is fired schedule another timer for
8 am and so on.This thing should work fine till the time DST does not come into 
picture as when the  DST starts the already scheduled timer will be fired 1 hour later than the actual time.

The `public void schedule(TimerTask task,Date time)`   api takes a date object , however once the
timer is scheduled even if the dst changes it will be fired according to the new time, not at the actual 
time.
Could someone provide some inputs to achieve this ?

Comment: You should consider using a job scheduler, such as [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: @Matt I wish I could use one. We can't use third party apis